# Set Mask For Window Using Qml & PySide6 Integration

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml, pyside6

I migrated from **PyQt5** to (**PySide6 & QML**) and I want to learn.
All I wanna do is creating a real rounded window or masked window.
Also I need to know how can I interact with main.qml and make changes on it inside of python code **main.py**
for example if I needed to use method setTitle or setFixedsize of QMainWindow
How can I do that?

inside **main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    color: "black"

    Rectangle {
        id: root
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "transparent"
        radius: 20

        Image {
            id: bgimg
            smooth: false
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "images/background.png"
        }
    }
}
```

inside **main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__=="__main__":

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    engine.load('main.qml')

    # SET MASK FOR WINDOW HERE

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The window in `main.qml` is the first object from `win = engine.rootObjects()[0]`.
(*[PySide6 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtQml/QQmlApplicationEngine.html#PySide6.QtQml.PySide6.QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine.rootObjects)*)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need is `OpacityMask`. To use it successfully, we have to make the following changes:

1. `root` and `bgimg` should be top-level (right now you have `bgimg` inside of `root`)
2. `root` and `bgimg` should be hidden with `visible: false`.
3. `root` should remove `color: "transparent"` since it needs to have color for the `OpacityMask` to work, but that's okay since `visible: false`
4. `root` should not set `width` and `height` since that clashes with `anchors.fill: parent`
5. As you're using Qt6, the 5.15 version numbers in your imports are no longer required

Here are all the changes applied:

```
import QtQuick // Removed 2.15 from import
import QtQuick.Controls // Removed 2.15 from import
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    color: "black"

    Rectangle {
        id: root
        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: 20
        visible: false // Added this property
        // Removed color: "transparent"
    }

    Image {
        id: bgimg
        smooth: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "images/background.png"
        visible: false // Added this property
    }

    // Added OpacityMask here
    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: bgimg
        maskSource: root
    }
}
```